# Get user who ran Query MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

Is there a way to obtain user who ran a query if I have the sql_handle, query_hash, plan_handle, query_plan_hash? Could I use any of these data points to find out the user who ran the query?

Answer (score 4):

No.  Query plans are shared across sessions, and by default there's no historical record of which sessions ran which queries.

You can capture this data with [Audit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15) or [Extended Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/extended-events?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Hi, David! What's about user_id from sys.dm_exec_plan_attributes in case the value is not -2?

Comment: "Value of -2 indicates that the batch submitted does not depend on implicit name resolution and can be shared among different users. This is the preferred method. Any other value represents the user ID of the user submitting the query in the database." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-plan-attributes-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15  IE if the object names in the query are resolved relative to a user's default schema it may not be reusable by other users.

Comment: So, in case somewhere in the statement a table was called without its schema name we theoretically could get who ran that statement by the user_id?

Comment: Sometimes.  But in the normal case where the user's default schema is `dbo` and the objects are in the `dbo` schema, user_id in that DMV will be 1, the user_id of `dbo`.  As the plan can be reused by any user whose default_schema is `dbo`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, David! I have checked it out and now could confidently say that  in fact the field named user_id contains schema_id of the default schema of a user who ran the query.

Comment: Yes. Good catch.  It's the schema_id from sys.schemas, not the principal_id from sys.database_principals.

Comment: If we can match on 1 which is default dbo. I am ok with that 97% of our tables are dbo any way so that is better than 0. If this is possible how would you join the two tables?

Comment: It would join to sys.database_principals on default_schema_name.  So it wouldn't you could not tell which of the users with default_schema of dbo ran the query.