# MS SQL Server : How to get query history along with SQL id and the user who triggered the query

Tags: query

I know this is a duplicate one. But i did not find a solution for my requirement in this forum.

Is there a way to identify the list of completed queries that were triggered along with its SQL ID and user details in SQL server for a particular day.

Expected Output:

SQL_ID, Query_Start_Time, Query_End_Time, Query_Executed, User

Comment: Duplicates: [Get user who ran Query MSSQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/297827/get-user-who-ran-query-mssql), [Logging queries and other T-SQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40960/logging-queries-and-other-t-sql/41011#41011)

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this two ways:

1. Setup an [Audit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16)

> Auditing an instance of the SQL Server Database Engine or an individual database involves tracking and logging events that occur on the Database Engine. SQL Server audit lets you create server audits, which can contain server audit specifications for server level events, and database audit specifications for database level events. Audited events can be written to the event logs or to audit files.

2. Create [Extended Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/quick-start-extended-events-in-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16)

> Extended Events is a lightweight performance monitoring system that enables users to collect data needed to monitor and troubleshoot problems in SQL Server. See [Extended Events overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/extended-events?view=sql-server-ver16) to learn more about the extended events architecture... By using Extended Events, you can see details about the inner operations of the SQL system and your application. When you create an Extended Events session, you tell the system:
>
> - Which occurrences you are interested in.
> - How you want the system to report the data to you.